# How do I find what are the properties of indexedDB objects and events?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I have been unable to find information listing what I can get from the event object returned to a `onsuccess` or `onerror` callback for different operations. [This Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB) is the most detailed info I've found but nowhere does it mention this.

For example:

```
var req = indexedDB.open( "mydb" );

req.onsuccess = function(evt)
{
    //I know this only from examples, but how else can I know what 
    //evt.target.result would refer to? And what else is in evt?
    var db = evt.target.result;
}
```

And another "success" callback:

```
var req = myObjectStore.add( someData );

req.onsuccess = function(evt)
{
    //What does this refer to? What else is in the event object?
    var whatIsThis = evt.target.result;
}
```

Comment: try `console.dir(evt)`

Comment: @JoshFroelich Thanks, but couldn't those property choices change? Sicne they're not a documented part of the spec (that I can find), couldn't they suddenly change? For example, doing that code on an event returned from `transaction.oncomplete`shows the transaction as the `target` and `event.target.db` as the database (in Firefox), but couldn't each browser decide to implement that differently or change it at some point? So they might choose to make it consistent with others and make `event.target.result` be the db?

Comment: @JoshFroelich Also, I'd need to somehow cause every handler to get called (`onblocked`, `onerror`, etc) to know what it is in each.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is most confusing aspect of IndexedDB API. Since the API documentation is for browser implementation, it is not clear for developer.

It is like this. Each request issue an operation and which is defined by one of [the algorithms](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#algorithms). The API doc will tell you what algorithm will run for each operation. These algorithm always return a value (may be undefined), which is set to the event target result. So check the return value of the algorithm.